# PHP - Read a result txt file to get vars

Tags: php, mysql, text-files

what I'm trying to do looks impossible with my actual PHP skills. Below you can find an exemple of a race result file, in txt. This file is composed of :

```
dir= the-track-file-name
longname= the-track-long-name-with-spaces
firstlap= the number of gate (checkpoint) the first lap is composed of
normallap= the number of gate (checkpoint) other laps are composed of
holeshotindex= thefirst gate after the start, which determine which player started first
time= the race duration, in minutes
laps= the number of laps (if minutes + laps, laps are counted when time's up)
starttime=1793
date= timestamp of the start
players:(under this line are all the player, just 1 in this exemple)
slot=0 (this is the multiplayer server slot taken by the player)
uid=5488 (this is the unique ID of the player)
number=755 (player's race number)
bike=rm125 (player's motorbike model)
name=Nico #755(player's name)
times: (under this line are things like timestamps of every gate, like SLOT|GATE|TIME)
0 0 1917 (it's like divide the timstamp /128 sounds good)
0 1 2184
(and etc, see full exemple below...)
```

The game server is on a dedicated ubuntu.
At each race end I send these results on an FTP web server, and what I need is to get vars to output something readable like a table with results after selecting a race (in a dropdown list i.e.).
Doing the table isn't the problem. 
My problem is, even searching a lot here, that I don't know how to read the txt to obtain this kind of page (only RESULTS table) : http://mxsimulator.com/servers/q2.MXSConcept.com/races/6015.html

Here is a full sample result file : http://www.mediafire.com/view/3b34a4kd5nfsj4r/sample_result_file.txt

Thank you

Comment: where starts the results? line number i mean?

Comment: It is possible the parse that kind of file with PHP but it's not very easy since there are just very few delimiters or stop-words in this format.

You can write an easy parser if you are assuming that "=" and ":" are the delimiters to make the "cuts" but if the format changes (or names can contain ":") it wont work. So you need to make sure what kind of chars are allowed in the file.

Comment: Why not fix the problem at its root and use a common format like JSON/XML/YAML for the export file? This way it's a pretty easy task to read the file on the PHP side...

Comment: I can't change the file form, it's generated by the game itself.
I tried far, be sure, with html DOM parser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, tonight it's file parsing time.

I've written a very basic parser, which walks through the data line by line.
First it looks for "=". When a "=" is found the line is split/exploded at "=".
You get two parts: before and after the "=".
I've used them as key and value in an $results array.

This process continues till we reach the line "times:".
That's the line indicating that on the next line (line "times:" + 1) the results start.
The results are "slot gate time" separated by spaces. So the results are exploded with " " (space) this time and you get the three parts.
I've inserted an array key 'times' which contains an array with named keys (slot,gate,time).

You might just look at the structure of the $results array.
It should be very easy to iterate over it to render a table or output data.

```
#$datafile = 'http://www.mediafire.com/view/3b34a4kd5nfsj4r/sample_result_file.txt';
#$lines = file_get_contents($datafile);

$lines = '
dir=Dardon-Gueugnon
longname=Dardon Gueugnon
firstlap=72
normallap=71
holeshotindex=1
time=0
laps=6
starttime=1846
date=1407162774
players:
slot=0
uid=8240
number=172
bike=rm125
name=Maximilien Jannot | RH-Factory
slot=1
uid=7910
number=666
bike=rm125
name=Patrick Corvisier|Team RH-Factory
slot=2
uid=10380
number=114
bike=rm125
name=Benoit Krawiec | MXS-Concept.com
slot=6
uid=6037
number=59
bike=rm125
name=Yohan Levrage | SPEED
slot=8
uid=6932
number=447
bike=rm125
name=Morgan Marlet | Mxs-Concept.com
times:
6 0 1974
1 0 1989
0 0 2020
2 0 2056
6 1 2242
1 1 2260
0 1 2313
2 1 2338
6 2 2434
1 2 2452';

$results = array();

$parseResults = false;

#foreach($lines as $line){ // use this line when working with file_get_contents

foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $lines) as $line){     

    if($parseResults === true) {
        $parts = explode(' ', $line); // SLOT|GATE|TIME = parts 0|1|2
        $times = array(
            'slot' => $parts[0],
            'gate' => $parts[1],
            'time' => $parts[2]
        );
        $results['times'][] = $times;
    }

    if(false !== strpos($line, '=')) { // if line has a = in it, explode it
        $parts = explode('=', $line);    
        $results[$parts[0]] = $parts[1]; // assign parts to array as key=value
    }

    if(false !== strpos($line, 'times:')) {
        // we reached "times:", let's set a flag to start reading results in the next iteration
        $parseResults = true;
    }
}

var_dump($results);
```

Output:

```
array(15) { 
["dir"]=> string(15) "Dardon-Gueugnon" 
["longname"]=> string(15) "Dardon Gueugnon" 
....
["name"]=> string(31) "Morgan Marlet | Mxs-Concept.com" 
["times"]=> array(10) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { ["slot"]=> string(1) "6" ["gate"]=> string(1) "0" ["time"]=> string(4) "1974" } 
    [1]=> array(3) { ["slot"]=> string(1) "1" ["gate"]=> string(1) "0" ["time"]=> string(4) "1989" } 
    [2]=> array(3) { ["slot"]=> string(1) "0" ["gate"]=> string(1) "0" ["time"]=> string(4) "2020" } 
...
} } }
```

Comment: looks nice, thanks, I'll try this afternoon and give an update

Comment: I got an error whith output :
 unexpected '{' on line :
`array(15) {`

Comment: `array(15) {`belongs to the output of `var_dump($results);`. I can't reproduce the error. So which line is it?

Comment: Sorry. I'm really tired this afternoon.